# Why are CASE-expressions in the list documenting operator precedence?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, syntax, parse

In the list here:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/operator-precedence/

case-expressions are put at the same precedence level as `BETWEEN`, between the `NOT` operator and the comparison operators.

However, case-expressions always begin with `CASE` and end with `END`, and all subexpressions are also delimited by the `CASE` keywords. They're like parenthetical expressions, so I don't understand why case-expressions are on this list.

Is there an SQL expression that would be parsed differently if the case-expression precedence was set higher or lower?

To give an example, with `2 + 3 * 4`, we get different results when parentheses are used in these 2 ways: `2 + (3 * 4)` and `(2 + 3) * 4`. This question is about how it's impossible to do the same with `CASE`. One can't substitute the use of `+` for `CASE` and show 2 different uses of parentheses such that the result differs between them.

To compare with other RDBMSes, neither [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#operators) nor [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE) include `CASE` in their operator precedence lists.

Comment: I think you're right. there's only one way to parse it because not other interpretations are valid. Alll other operators are two argument, before and after, just after like `~` or `!`, or odd like `binary`, and `case` is self enclosed with not real arguments. precedence on a self contained expression is a bit meaningless which is why `(`/`)` are in the table either..

Comment: @danblack Even more confusing is that the table seems to be an accurate reflection of [the source code](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.5/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L1167). Which makes me wonder how an expression like `1 + case when 1 then 1 end` works. `CASE` is probably the only exception where an expression can have a subexpression that uses an operator of lower precedence without requiring parentheses. I mean, despite the code being so, the behaviour of the parser is as if `CASE` were of the highest precedence, as it can only be.

Comment: @danblack I want to read the commit history around the addition of that line, but it seems that history is not available. It's added to mysql's repo as part of a huge commit, child of the root commit, with the message "Import changeset".

Comment: @danblack *"the only exception where a **binary operator** expression can have a subexpression that uses an operator of lower precedence without requiring parentheses." Corrected because subexpressions of case can use operators of lower precedence. However, it's true, `1 + NOT 0` is a syntax error. I would have expected `1 + CASE ...` to also raise a syntax error given its supposed precedence level.

Comment: when you think about it, precedence is effectively how to parse the expression. If you want to see how things are parsed I suggest adding a debugger to the source code and seeing what happens. Or understanding bison files. [Case with subexpression](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.5/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L4000-L4001) `expr_lex` also appears in `IF` expressions and a number of statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is like that because it's an accurate reflection of [this part of the source code](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/c69520c9dfa6e4a26258842a1d3512c2b5d43d56/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L1167):

```
%left   OR_SYM OR2_SYM
%left   XOR
%left   AND_SYM AND_AND_SYM

%left   PREC_BELOW_NOT
%left   NOT_SYM

%left   BETWEEN_SYM CASE_SYM WHEN_SYM THEN_SYM ELSE
%left   '=' EQUAL_SYM GE '>' LE '<' NE IS LIKE SOUNDS_SYM REGEXP IN_SYM
%left   '|'
%left   '&'
%left   SHIFT_LEFT SHIFT_RIGHT
%left   '-' '+' ORACLE_CONCAT_SYM
%left   '*' '/' '%' DIV_SYM MOD_SYM
%left   '^'
%left   MYSQL_CONCAT_SYM
%left   NEG '~' NOT2_SYM BINARY
```

That's despite how the parser behaves. Despite how, for example, `1 + NOT 0` raises a syntax error for following an operator of high precedence with one of lower precedence, `1 + CASE WHEN 1 THEN 1 END` doesn't raise a similar syntax error for the same reason. Any expression involving `CASE` treats it as an operator of the highest precedence.

I'm left wondering now why the source code is expressed like that despite it not behaving like that. Unfortunately, I lack knowledge of bison to make sense of this discrepancy without investing more time in this curiosity.